# Соединить два массива по индексу

Tags: javascript

есть 2 массива

```
array1 = ['11 dec', '12 dec', '13 dec'];
array2 = ['13:00','14:00','15:00'];
```

количество значений в нем одинаково
нужно соединить его в новый массив с таким результатом

```
array3 = ['11 dec 13:00', '12 dec 14:00', '13 dec 15:00']
```

голову сломал не понимаю куда копать
интернет поиск не дал результата, не допираю логику действий

пожалуйста подскажите

Comment: Вариантов масса, `forEach, for, while, map, filter, etc...` =) Самое быстрое будет сделать через `for`. Если вам важна производительность и будут перебираться большие массивы.

Answer (score 4):

```js
let array1 = ['11 dec', '12 dec', '13 dec'];
let array2 = ['13:00','14:00','15:00'];

let res = array1.map((elem, index) => `${elem}, ${array2[index]}`);

console.log(res);
```

Можно мапом пройтись. Но это только в твоём случае, когда 2 массива равной длины.

Answer (score 1):

Либо через `map`:

```js
array1 = ['11 dec', '12 dec', '13 dec'];
array2 = ['13:00','14:00','15:00'];

console.log(array1.map((e, i) => e + ' ' + array2[i]));
```